# Github action fail when deploy: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, github-actions, php-deployer

I have used a simple github action workflow for over one year to deploy my code to my server. Suddenly it gives me composer errors when i have not touched the composer file. Have not even run composer update.

The new error message:
[image]

`PHP Fatal error:  Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0". You are running 7.1.33-47+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1. in phar:///home/runner/.composer/vendor/deployer/deployer/dep/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24`

I use [deployer.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1PU5.png) with laravel recipe for deployment tool. And this is the deployer.php file

```
namespace Deployer;

require 'recipe/laravel.php';
require 'recipe/rsync.php';

set('application', 'Projsite Web App');
set('ssh_multiplexing', true);

set('rsync_src', function () {
    return __DIR__;
});

set('shared_dirs', ['/public/delivery_management_api/public/apd_attachments', 
                    '/public/delivery_management_api/public/waste_supplier_logos', 
                    '/public/delivery_management_api/public/rental_images',
                    '/public/delivery_management_api/public/request_images',
                    '/public/delivery_management_api/public/logistic_images',
                    '/public/delivery_management_api/public/organization_logos']);

set('shared_files', ['.env',
                     'public/delivery_management_api/.env',
                     'public/delivery_management_api/storage/logs/laravel.log']);


set('writable_dirs', ['bootstrap/cache',
                      'storage',
                      'storage/app',
                      'storage/app/public',
                      'storage/framework',
                      'storage/framework/cache',
                      'storage/framework/sessions',
                      'storage/framework/views',
                      'storage/logs',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/bootstrap/cache',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage/app',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage/app/public',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage/framework',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage/framework/cache',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage/framework/sessions',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage/framework/views',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage/logs']);
add('rsync', [
    'exclude' => [
        '.git',
        '/.env',
        '/storage/',
        '/vendor/',
        '/node_modules/',
        '.github',
        'deploy.php',
    ],
]);

task('deploy:secrets', function () {
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/.env', getenv('DOT_ENV'));
    upload('.env', get('deploy_path') . '/shared');
    
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/.env', getenv('API_DOT_ENV'));
    upload('.env', get('deploy_path') . '/shared/public/delivery_management_api');
});

host('app.projsite.com')
  ->hostname('94.46.44.17')
  ->stage('production')
  ->user('root')
  ->set('deploy_path', '/var/www/app');

host('dev.projsite.com')
  ->hostname('94.46.44.17')
  ->stage('staging')
  ->user('root')
  ->set('deploy_path', '/var/www/dev');

host('demo.projsite.com')
  ->hostname('94.46.44.17')
  ->stage('demo')
  ->user('root')
  ->set('deploy_path', '/var/www/demo');

after('deploy:failed', 'deploy:unlock');

desc('Deploy the application');

task('deploy', [
    'deploy:info',
    'deploy:prepare',
    'deploy:lock',
    'deploy:release',
    'rsync',
    'deploy:secrets',
    'deploy:shared',
    'deploy:vendors',
    'deploy:writable',
    'artisan:storage:link',
    'artisan:view:cache',
    'artisan:config:cache',
    'artisan:queue:restart',
    'deploy:symlink',
    'deploy:unlock',
    'cleanup',
]);
```

The github action yml file that gives me error and has been working for long time

```
   name: Deploy Project to STAGING Server
   runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
   needs: [build-js-staging, app-tests]
   if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging'
   steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v1
     - name: Fetch built assets from Artifacts
       uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
       with:
         name: assets
         path: public
     - name: Setup PHP
       uses: shivammathur/setup-php@master
       with:
         php-version: 7.1.25
         coverage: xdebug
     - name: Composer install
       run: composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
     - name: Composer install in API
       run: (cd public/delivery_management_api && composer install --ignore-platform-reqs)
     - name: Setup Deployer
       uses: atymic/deployer-php-action@master
       with:
         ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
         ssh-known-hosts: ${{ secrets.SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS }} 
     - name: Deploy to Prod
       env:
         DOT_ENV: ${{ secrets.DOT_ENV_STAGING }}
         API_DOT_ENV: ${{ secrets.API_DOT_ENV_STAGING }}
       run: dep deploy staging --tag=${{ env.GITHUB_REF }} -vvv
```

This is the composer.json file. I just added the "platform_check: false" under config but did not work

```
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.25",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "akaunting/language": "^1.0",
        "deployer/deployer": "^6.7",
        "deployer/recipes": "^6.2",
        "emarref/jwt": "^1.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5",
        "jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "platform-check": false,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.1.25",
            "ext-mongodb": "1.5.3"
        },
        "allow-plugins": {
            "kylekatarnls/update-helper": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

### **2 days later:**

I decided to upgrade the php on my server to 7.4.13. And also updated the yaml file php-version parameter to that version. I also upgraded the deployer version in composer file to 7.0 from 6.7 and followed [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nDOj.png) instructions

Now i get this error message:
[image]

```
::group::task deploy:info
task deploy:info
::group::task deploy:info
task deploy:info
::group::task deploy:setup
task deploy:setup
::group::task deploy:lock
task deploy:lock
::group::task deploy:release
task deploy:release
::group::task deploy:update_code
task deploy:update_code
  [*****] /usr/bin/php7.4 /home/runner/.composer/vendor/deployer/deployer/dep worker --port 36839 --task deploy:update_code --host ***** --tag staging -vvv
  [*****] ssh '-A' '-o' 'ControlMaster=auto' '-o' 'ControlPersist=60' '-o' 'ControlPath=/dev/shm/root@*****' 'root@*****' ': *****; bash -ls'
  [*****] run command -v 'git' || which 'git' || type -p 'git'
  [*****] mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
  [*****] /usr/bin/git
  [*****] ssh '-A' '-o' 'ControlMaster=auto' '-o' 'ControlPersist=60' '-o' 'ControlPath=/dev/shm/root@*****' 'root@*****' ': *****; bash -ls'
  [*****] run [ -d /var/www/dev/.dep/repo ] || mkdir -p /var/www/dev/.dep/repo
  [*****] mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
  [*****] ssh '-A' '-o' 'ControlMaster=auto' '-o' 'ControlPersist=60' '-o' 'ControlPath=/dev/shm/root@*****' 'root@*****' ': *****; bash -ls'
  [*****] run export GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT='0' GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new'; [ -f /var/www/dev/.dep/repo/HEAD ] || /usr/bin/git clone --mirror  /var/www/dev/.dep/repo 2>&1
  [*****] mesg: ttyname failed:
  [*****] Inappropriate ioctl for device
  [*****] fatal: repository '/var/www/dev/.dep/repo' does not exist
  [*****]  error  in update_code.php on line 90:
  [*****] exit code 128 (Invalid exit argument)
  ::group::task deploy:failed
task deploy:failed
  [*****] /usr/bin/php7.4 /home/runner/.composer/vendor/deployer/deployer/dep worker --port 36839 --task deploy:failed --host ***** --tag staging -vvv
  done on *****
  ::endgroup::
::group::task deploy:unlock
task deploy:unlock
  [*****] /usr/bin/php7.4 /home/runner/.composer/vendor/deployer/deployer/dep worker --port 36839 --task deploy:unlock --host ***** --tag staging -vvv
  [*****] ssh '-A' '-o' 'ControlMaster=auto' '-o' 'ControlPersist=60' '-o' 'ControlPath=/dev/shm/root@*****' 'root@*****' ': *****; bash -ls'
  [*****] run rm -f /var/www/dev/.dep/deploy.lock
  [*****] mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
  done on *****
  ::endgroup::
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

Updated deployer file:

```
<?php

namespace Deployer;

require 'recipe/laravel.php';
require 'contrib/rsync.php';
require 'recipe/common.php';
//require 'vendor/deployer/deployer/recipe/common.php';

set('application', 'Projsite Web App');
set('ssh_multiplexing', true);

set('rsync_src', function () {
    return __DIR__;
});

set('shared_dirs', ['/public/delivery_management_api/public/apd_attachments', 
                    '/public/delivery_management_api/public/waste_supplier_logos', 
                    '/public/delivery_management_api/public/rental_images',
                    '/public/delivery_management_api/public/request_images',
                    '/public/delivery_management_api/public/logistic_images',
                    '/public/delivery_management_api/public/organization_logos']);

set('shared_files', ['.env',
                     'public/delivery_management_api/.env',
                     'public/delivery_management_api/storage/logs/laravel.log']);


set('writable_dirs', ['bootstrap/cache',
                      'storage',
                      'storage/app',
                      'storage/app/public',
                      'storage/framework',
                      'storage/framework/cache',
                      'storage/framework/sessions',
                      'storage/framework/views',
                      'storage/logs',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/bootstrap/cache',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage/app',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage/app/public',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage/framework',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage/framework/cache',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage/framework/sessions',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage/framework/views',
                      'public/delivery_management_api/storage/logs']);
add('rsync', [
    'exclude' => [
        '.git',
        '/.env',
        '/storage/',
        '/vendor/',
        '/node_modules/',
        '.github',
        'deploy.php',
    ],
]);

task('deploy:secrets', function () {
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/.env', getenv('DOT_ENV'));
    upload('.env', get('deploy_path') . '/shared');
    
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/.env', getenv('API_DOT_ENV'));
    upload('.env', get('deploy_path') . '/shared/public/delivery_management_api');
});

host('app.projsite.com')
  ->setHostname('94.46.44.17')
  ->set('labels', ['stage' => 'production'])
  ->set('remote_user', 'root')
  ->set('deploy_path', '/var/www/app');

host('dev.projsite.com')
  ->setHostname('94.46.44.17')
  ->set('labels', ['stage' => 'staging'])
  ->set('remote_user', 'root')
  ->set('deploy_path', '/var/www/dev');

host('demo.projsite.com')
  ->setHostname('94.46.44.17')
  ->set('labels', ['stage' => 'demo'])
  ->set('remote_user', 'root')
  ->set('deploy_path', '/var/www/demo');

after('deploy:failed', 'deploy:unlock');

desc('Deploy the application');

task('deploy', [
    'deploy:info',
    'deploy:prepare',
    'deploy:lock',
    'deploy:release',
    'rsync',
    'deploy:secrets',
    'deploy:shared',
    'deploy:vendors',
    'deploy:writable',
    'artisan:storage:link',
    'artisan:view:cache',
    'artisan:config:cache',
    'artisan:queue:restart',
    'deploy:symlink',
    'deploy:unlock',
    'deploy:cleanup'
]);
```

Comment: It is self explanatory.... you have a dependency that required `PHP >= 7.3.0` and you have `7.1.25` in the `github action file`.... `deployer/deployer` already required `php >= 7.2` and `deployer/recipes` is abandoned... you are also using `laravel 5.6` long ago deprecated and not supported anymore.... you need to upgrade everything ASAP

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please add all error messages to your question in text form. Don't share text output hidden in screenshots

Comment: Done... iam sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The error is as clear as day and i would recommend you to read the errors and get an overview, because this is as explained in the exception as possible. On your action the `PHP` version is `7.1.x` and your composer file requires `7.3.x`.

If you read the documentation for the `PHP` [setup script](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-php-action). The version `7.3.x` is supported on the `ubuntu` version you are running. Updating the setup script should help.

```
 - name: Setup PHP
   uses: shivammathur/setup-php@master
   with:
     php-version: 7.4.30
     coverage: xdebug
```

Comment: Yes but this error appeared after no changes. The deployment had been working for over a year. That is why i questioned the even error message.

Comment: Anyways the status right now is that i updated our server to php 7.4.13 and ofcourse changed the 'php-version' parameter in the yaml file to 7.4.13. I also upgraded deployer from 6.7 to 7.0 and followed these instruction https://deployer.org/docs/7.x/UPGRADE. And now i get an new error messsage. I will edit the question above to se details